# passing input value as session variable

Tags: php, pdo, session-variables

I have an input field named `qty` which value has to be passed to next page named update_cart to be processed. I tried this with using session variables. But when i try to send it via `$_Post` or `$_Get` it does not work as intended. Any suggestions please.The code i have tried is given below:

**cart.php**

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
echo "<th>Price (USD)</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "<th>Updated price</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$query = "SELECT * FROM sub_products WHERE sub_p_id IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY name";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

$total_price=0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
extract($row);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>&#36;".$row['price']."</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='number' name='qty' value='' max='10'>";
$_SESSION['qty']=2 ; //here i want to pass value of "qty"
echo "<a href='update_cart.php?id={$id}&name=".$row['name']."&price=".$row['price']."&qty=".$_SESSION['qty']."' class='btn btn-danger'>";
 echo "<span </span> Update Price </a>";
 $total_price+=$price;
  }
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Total</b></td>";
echo "<td>&#36;{$total_price}</td>";
```

**update_cart.php**

```
session_start();
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty=$_SESSION['qty'];
$price=isset($_GET['price'])? $_GET['price']: "";
$price=$price*$qty;
echo $qty;
header('Location: cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=' . $id . '&name=' . $name . '&price='.$price . '&qty='.$qty);
```

Comment: Can you post the result of the `update_cart.php?id...` link from the `cart.php`, please? Also, why are you defining a session variable if you are just sending it in the link?

Comment: Have you session_start(); before $_SESSION['qty']=2 ; in your cart.php?

Comment: @FirstOne because i want to pass the values to `update_cart.php` to get the updated price back on `cart.php`. I have edited `update_cart.php` check it out please.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis yes i have. It works perfect when i pass it like the way i have mentioned i.e `$_SESSION['qty']=2` but i dont want to pass value 2 . I want to pass the value of input.

Comment: Can you show the html you have for the form?

Comment: Is the form with the `qty` field in the `cart.php` file?

Comment: @FirstOne yes it is in `cart.php`

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis edited `cart.php`

Comment: i see both files calling each other. please clarify what is the order

Comment: @FirstOne i am filling it. But it posts empty `qty` in a link. When i write it like this `$_Session['qty']=$_Post['qty']`.

Comment: TBH, I still don't see the need of a session variable if you are explicitly passing it as GET.

Comment: @Aris It is  a simple cart in which cart items are shown in `cart.php` and with each item there is an input field for quantity. All i want is to pass quantity value to the next page `update_cart` as session variable to be multiplied with the price given and retrieve back the updated price

Comment: now it's more clear, but you have an answer as well :)

Comment: @Aris but i am confused how to pass a value in session variable

Comment: first you send it a GET. then you must read it and add it in the session. it's a 2 steps process.

Comment: @Aris ` $qty=$_GET['qty']`
        `$_SESSION['qty']=$qty;` i tried this. but it gives an error

Comment: it says. `Undefined index: qty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first neet to get the quantity from your `GET` variable.

```
$qty = isset($_GET['qty']) ? $_GET['qty'] : 1;
$_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
```

Or simplified:

```
$_SESSION['qty'] = isset($_GET['qty']) ? $_GET['qty'] : 1;
```

You cannot add values to variables without submitting the form because PHP is a server-side language. As soon as the page is displayed, PHP has it's work done and cannot change.

### Update

To make it a bit easier for you, I'll show you how to work with forms.

#### cart.php

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
echo "<th>Price (USD)</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "<th>Updated price</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$query = "SELECT * FROM sub_products WHERE sub_p_id IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY name";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

$total_price=0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
extract($row);
?>
<tr>
    <form method="POST" action="update_cart.php">
    <td><?= $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td>&#36; <?= $row['price']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type='number' name='qty' value='' max='10'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $row['name']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= $row['price']; ?>" />
    </form>
</tr>
```

#### update_cart.php

Change:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$qty=$_SESSION['qty'];
$price=isset($_GET['price'])? $_GET['price']: "";
$price=$price*$qty;
```

to:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$qty=$_SESSION['qty'];
$price=isset($_POST['price'])? $_POST['price']: "";
$price=$price*$qty;
```

Comment: @tabia The way you are trying to use a session is impossible. I'll edit my question to show you a better option.

Comment: after changing one line in your `cart_update.php` code it worked perfecty!! :) i just changed `$qty=$_Post'qty'];`